# PHPExcel Error in IIS Error loading file: Could not open temp/ for reading! File does not exist

Tags: php, iis, phpexcel

I'm having an error. read all i can on the Internet. Still NO LUCK.. I Hope someone could answer this regarding PHPExcel in Windows IIS
here is my code which works well with XAMPP (but not in IIS):

```
  <?php  set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');

    /** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "temp/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]) ;

    $inputFileName = "temp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];  // File to read
    //echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />';
    try {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
print_r($sheetData);
$bilang=0;
$pumasok=0;
$hindi=0;
$iHerd= $_SESSION['urHerd'];
$iAnit = 1;
foreach($sheetData as $rec)
{   
$bilang++;
//////etc etc
}
?>
```

I'm getting this error:
Error loading file "Animal.xlsx": Could not open temp/Animal.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Have you tried checking the result of `move_uploaded_file()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by changing read-write permissions of the folder where the PHPExcel Class uses as temporary folder which I have set in my php code for importing filed.... thank you very much for your time viewing

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
use PHPExcel_Settings;
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

After line code require "PHPExcel.php"